# Python3: replace md5 by hashlib

Tags: python-3.x, md5, hashlib

I am trying to use the eventful API with Python3. In its current state, the function to log in uses the md5 library which is deprecated. Consequently, I would like to convert this function to be Python 3 compatible. The line I am facing difficulties with is :

```
response = md5.new(nonce + ':'+ md5.new(password).hexdigest()).hexdigest()
```

My try to convert it is

```
    mpwd = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
    apwd = mpwd.hexdigest()
    s = nonce+":"+apwd
    mall = hashlib.md5(s.encode())
    response = mall.hexdigest()
```

Unfortunately, the API returns an error that says that either the login or the password is incorrect. However, I checked both and it is ok. So could you please tell me what's wrong with my code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you really should have tried before posting:

Python 2.7:

```
>>> import md5
>>> password = 'fred'
>>> nonce = '12345'
>>> md5.new(nonce + ':'+ md5.new(password).hexdigest()).hexdigest()
'496a1ca20abf5b0b12ab7f9891d04201'
```

Python 2.7 and Python 3.6:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> password = 'fred'
>>> nonce = '12345'
>>> mpwd = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
>>> apwd = mpwd.hexdigest()
>>> s = nonce+":"+apwd
>>> mall = hashlib.md5(s.encode())
>>> mall.hexdigest()
'496a1ca20abf5b0b12ab7f9891d04201'
```

As you can see, both versions produce the same md5 hash. So the problem isn't with your code. It may relate to what you are doing with `response` after this bit of code. Or maybe the API is correct and the login really is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct. 
If you add hashlib before md5 and put "#" before import md5, problem would be solved.

import hashlib
(delete "import md5" from the file)

```
def login(self, user, password):
    "Login to the Eventful API as USER with PASSWORD."
    nonce = self.call('/users/login')['nonce']
    response = hashlib.md5.new(nonce + ':'+ hashlib.md5.new(password).hexdigest()).hexdigest()

    login = self.call('/users/login', user=user, nonce=nonce,
                      response=response)
    self.user_key = login['user_key']
    self.user = user
    return user
```

Comment: It's better if you rewrite the code in your answer, with your changes included